# Как убрать дефолтные стили в ios

Tags: ios, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли убрать дефолтные стили на айфонах, айпадах и т.д. **reset.css** не помогает.

В частости, кнопка **input type="submit"** не хочет принимать указанный стиль.

Кроме того, телефонный номер на **iPhone** отображается синим шрифтом... как ему задать желаемый цвет?

Есть у кого-нибудь соображения на сей предмет?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Павел Азанов, то есть?

Я задавал стили для p.phone {} - не сработало. Почему должно сработать с элементом span?

Comment: Это предположение, к сожалению не могу проверить сейчас

Comment: С номером, к сожалению, оба варианта не помогли.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то выключить стандартную стилизацию элемента можно прописав ему CSS свойство:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

С телефонами можно попробовать два варианта, добавить в head:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

или через CSS:

```
a[href^=tel]{
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо! С input type="submit" помогло. А про телефонные номера не в курсе? Как им задать стиль?

Comment: Не за что, обновил ответ по вопросу о телефонах.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень выручили.

Comment: Сейчас к сожалению проверить нет возможности, но, что если номер телефона находится не в ссылке а в абзаце?

    <p>+7(922)258-85-48</p>

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы при этом телефон оставался кликабельным.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать окружной тэг для телефона (span), и прописать стили для него. По поводу кликабельноси - возможно есть проблемы с первым способом.